# Different popup for every polygon (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet

I'm making a map [(you can see here)](https://micmicto.github.io/mapplugins)  with different markers and layers to group these markers. I added polygons in another layer (Poligono layer), and I want to know if exist a way to add different information on each polygons that after can be show on a popup.

I can add different information on each marker using this

```
        L.marker ([21.017697, -89.641353], {icon:hospitalIcon}).bindPopup('Info info info').addTo(hospitales),
```

Exist a way to add information for each polygon using something like .bindPopup for the polygons I am using?

```
L.polygon ([
        [20.6894, -88.2017],
        [20.572997, -88.730264],
        [20.3457, -88.1677], 
    ]).addTo(polygon),
```

Something like the image. When you click, show information, I need to show different information for each polygon.

[image]

and you can see [the complete code](https://github.com/micmicto/mapplugins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [Leaflet API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#layer), you'll see that `bindPopup` is a method of `L.Layer`, so all interactive map layers have it. Lines, polygons, markers, circles, etc.

So, it is perfectly possible to do something like:

```
var poly1 = L.polygon(coordinatesForPolygon1).bindPopup('One');
var poly2 = L.polygon(coordinatesForPolygon2).bindPopup('Two');
```

Let me also copy-paste a bit of code from the [Leaflet tutorial on map panes](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/), that shows you that you can bind popups iterating through a list of polygons (or in a loop, or etc):

```
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, From now on I will read the documentation better